# Está correto misturar o código PHP ao HTML?

Tags: php, html, front-end, back-end

Estou reiniciando meus estudos na área de TI e estou com essa dúvida.
No curso que estou fazendo os exemplos mostram o código php misturado e inserido ao código html. É assim mesmo que funciona na prática? Tenho uma pulga atrás da orelha me dizendo que isso não é uma boa prática. Se for assim mesmo, como os desenvolvedores back e front dividem o código?

A minha dúvida não é saber o que é Front e Back, é entender porque o codigo php ta junto com o html. Se fazem isso mesmo no dia-a-dia das empresas.

Comment: Você quer realmente saber a nível de PHP ou independente de linguagem? Back e front também pode ser aplicado em outros contextos, como mobile ou mesmo desktop.

Comment: acredito que para o meu nível elucidaria mais a questão saber a nivel de php

Comment: Ter um `foreach` ou até mesmo um `if` simples dentro de tags html não tem problema. O problema mesmo é aquele script gigante de 1200 com lógica de negocios, apresentação e sabe lá o que mais.

Comment: Em alguns casos você perceberá que juntar código PHP com HTML pode te ajudar. Mas como o @rray disse, o problema está no excesso. Em querer transferir a responsabilidades de classes para a sua página PHP que contém HTML e transformar em um arquivo gigante e difícil de compreender. Eu particularmente prefiro separar o máximo e fazer as interações das páginas PHP com templates HTML via javascript. Mas isso não é uma regra e você pode escolher o que for melhor para você ou para o seu projeto!